# How do I convert the command in NSDate to show Hebrew calendar date?

Tags: ios, nsdate

That's my code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[_label setText:dateString];
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i'm aware, you need to set the calender of your date formatter (and possibly the locale too).

Set the calendar:

```
[dateFormat setCalendar:[[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:kCFHebrewCalendar] autorelease]];
```

Set the locale:

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:kCFHebrewCalendar] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use `setCalendar` method of `NSDateFormatter`  like:

```
NSCalendar *hebrew = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSHebrewCalendar];
[dateFormat setCalendar:hebrew ];
```

2) Also you can use:

```
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendar * hebrew = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSHebrewCalendar];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:date];
NSDate *hebrewDate = [hebrew dateFromComponents:components];
```